# How do I add angled borders to the sides of a navigation menu?

Tags: css, navbar

I want to make a navbar similar to the one pictured below, however I'm struggling to figure out how to get the borders on the edges to be angled and with the shadow look.

[image: Navbar with angled edge borders]

I'm using Bootstrap's navbar example as a starter to build the page:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="http://localhost/mxvsatv/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

The styling I found used in the image is below, but not sure how to make it do that:

```
header.gamez-header-variation-1 .top-menu-container:before {
content: "";
border-top: 100px solid rgba(15, 27, 51, 0.18);
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
width: 117%;
left: -8.5%;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;}
header.gamez-header-variation-1 .top-menu-container:after {
content: "";
border-top: 90px solid rgba(15, 27, 51, 0.45);
border-left: 90px solid transparent;
border-right: 90px solid transparent;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px -14px 13px rgba(0, 213, 197, 0.8));
filter: drop-shadow(0px -14px 13px rgba(0, 213, 197, 0.8));
position: absolute;
width: 110%;
left: -5%;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many methods to achieve this, you could use `clip-path` or `pseudo` selector, or even `transform`. So, it's always depends on how you build it, doesn't matter is it the hard way or easy way. As long as you get what you want,  you're good to go, but if you find an easier way to do it, then this would be a plus for you.

@bntzio mentioned [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)- a useful tool that will give you what you want.

Also, you can read these reference to learn more about clip-path:

[CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) and [Viget](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms) both are great references and I encourage you to check them out.

here is a sample of what have you asked for :

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  background: #276E8E;
}
div.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}
div.box-container {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}
div.box-one {
 position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.05);
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 99%, 20% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 99%, 20% 100%);
}
div.box-two {
  background: rgba(19,80,98, 0.8);
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 99%, 20% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 99%, 20% 100%);

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-one">
   <div class="box-container">   
    <div class="box-two">
      <div class="content">
      <!-- content here -->
      </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is by using a background image for that.

Comment: I would like to avoid using background image. Seems like a cheap workaround

Comment: Then I think [this](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes) might be helpful.

Comment: That looks promising. Thank you Werner!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that effect by just using an image, and place menu links on top of it, or you can do it with the `clip-path` css property.

The `clip-path` property allows you to make complex shapes in CSS by clipping an element to a basic shape (circle, ellipse, polygon, or inset), or to an SVG source.

For example:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 81% 54%, 19% 54%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 81% 54%, 19% 54%);
```

Check out [this tool](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to play with the `clip-path` property.

Comment: I like the tool. That could come in handy! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use `pseudo` selectors `before` and after the nav

```
 /* this will add a triangle to the left of the nav */
 nav:before {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
/* this will add a triangle to the right of the nav */
nav:after {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid green;
}
```

Tweak it up depending upon your needs.

Comment: The tweaks are what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Ummm what's so confusing in that ?

Comment: change the border top,bottom and left to increase or decrease size of triangle

Comment: use transform rotate to rotate the triangles and that's pretty much it